# Call (Fetch - Insert -Update) salesforce objects from .NET application and viceversa

Tags: apex, soap-api, soap, wsdl2apex

I am curious to know about best approach i can follow to overcome my assignment.

I have tried to call External Web services using  APEX class and WSDL generation in Salesforce.

e.g GetQuote function from http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx?op=GetQuote

By passing param = CTSH

Or direct link http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx/GetQuote?symbol=CTSH

I have successfully implemented that by importing WSDL file and making its APEX class.

Now i want to make something like above example in .NET application.

My goal is sync the Salesforce object data and .NET application data,

1> After creating Opportunity in SF , i want to insert Opportunity details in my .NET application DB. along with Account and Contact related to that Opportunity.
I can achieve this using web service / SOAP / WSDL.

2> When i do something in .NET application , i need to create CASE and may be sometime update CASE in Salesforce using .NET code.

Diagram below can be more helpful to understand my problem.

==================================================================================
**salesforce to .NET communication**

## [image: salesforce to .NET communication]

**.NET to salesforce Communication**
[image: .NET to salesforce Communication]

Please guide me in this , any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there a more specific question here? It is certainly possible to have Salesforce callout to a .NET based SOAP based web service as required. You can also have a .NET application establish a session back to Salesforce and create/update records. Exactly how you do this will depend on: * how many records you are dealing with * how frequently you want to sync the data * how many api calls you can use based on the license and number of seats * if you need to use a dedicated api user.

Comment: it may be in your best interest to investigate the developerforce .net tookit.

https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-Toolkit-for-NET